# Trying to find the count of customers and add the sales of the customer in based on their purchase frequency on SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to find the customer count and sales by the number of times they have purchased in 2019

```
txn_date Customer_ID  Transaction_Number    Sales        Reference(not in the SQL table)    
1/2/2019    1           12345                $10           First Purchase SLS
4/3/2019    1           65890                $20           Second Purchase SLS
3/22/2019   3           64453                $30           First Purchase SLS
4/3/2019    4           88567                $20           First Purchase SLS
1/23/2019   5           89464                $40           First Purchase SLS
4/3/2019    5           99674                $30           Second Purchase SLS
4/3/2019    6           32224                $20           First Purchase SLS
1/23/2019   6           46466                $30           Second Purchase SLS
```

I am trying to get the below result:

```
               Customer_Count   Transaction_Count   Sum(Sales)
1st Purchase        5                 5                 $120
2nd Purchase        3                 3                 $80
```

I have tried the below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT INDIVIDUAL_ID),
CASE WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 1 THEN '1'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 2 THEN '2'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 3 THEN '3'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 4 THEN '4'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS  >= 5 THEN '5+' END AS TXN_TYPE,
SUM(DOLLAR_VALUE_US), 
SUM( COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS)

FROM customerorder

GROUP BY CASE WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 1 THEN '1'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 2 THEN '2'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 3 THEN '3'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS = 4 THEN '4'
WHEN COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS  >= 5 THEN '5+' END
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

I want to find the count of the customers and their sales. So for the 1st purchase the customer count would be anyone who has made atleast one purchase and the amount of Sales. For the 2nd purchase it should technically include every one who has made the first purchase but only the sales from the second transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to enumerate the orders for each customer and then aggregate:

```
select seqnum, count(*) as num_customers, sum(sales)
from (select co.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by txn_date) as seqnum
      from customerorder co
     ) co
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: I want to find the count of the customers and their sales. So for the 1st purchase the customer count would be anyone who has made atleast one purchase and the amount of Sales. For the 2nd purchase it should technically include every one who has made the first purchase but only the sales from the second transaction.

Comment: I think the query which I have out together is categorizing the customers by their number of transactions. which I think is not correct.

Comment: @Somya . . . This query should be doing what you want.